# Adobe Air - StageWebView Meta Title

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to get the meta title of a .html document loaded over StageWebView?
My code:

```
webViewC.stage = cont.stage;
webViewC.viewPort = new Rectangle(cont.x,cont.y,cont.width,cont.height);
webViewC.loadURL("http://www.example.com/foobar.html");
```

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StageWebView` is a very low level abstraction of core HTML rendering components on the target platform. As such, it provides very little interaction between ActionScript and the underlying HTML document.

If you are just looking for the documents' `<title>` element, then that is available through the `webViewC.title` getter once the `Event.COMPLETE` event has been raised. But if you are looking for the content of the `<meta name='Title' content='...' />` element, then there is no way to access that through `StageWebView`.

I'm not quite sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you might be a [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to retrieve the contents of the page, and then parse out the information that you want, then pass the raw HTML blob to `webViewC.loadString()`